# Mac Terminal is stuck

Tags: terminal

I get this message every time I open the terminal on my Mac:

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...
...completed.

[Process completed]

No matter what I do it always appears. I have closed out of the application, created a new window, even shut down my computer and restarted the whole system. Nevertheless, this message still appears and I cannot enter anything into the terminal. I am getting concerned because I have the feeling I royally messed something up.

EDIT: I found the fix, I needed to go to Terminal->Preferences and make it so the Shell opens with

/bin/sh

in the Command(complete path).
Now to figure out how to reset the Default login shell

Comment: Not a Mac user, but a fan :)  Are there any TEMP or cache folders on a Mac?  I would delete them all...then restart

Comment: What OS version are you running?

Comment: macOS High Sierra